# SQL Split to columns

Tags: sql

How split sql to columns?

Example

```
ID
123456-01-F100
222222-18-400A
```

Split to

```
ID     | Item | Form
123456 |  01  | F100
222222 |  18  | 400A
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: Do a little searching here on your title.  There are scores of examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL you can use `split_part()`

```
select split_part(id, '-', 1) as id, 
       split_part(id, '-', 2) as item,
       split_part(id, '-', 3) as "from"
from the_table;
```